# Jquery : Connect list counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery connect list and a counter. The first list(sortable 1) contains the values and the second list (sortable 2) is empty. Everytime I drag and drop an item, the counter goes + 1 that part works but my issue is everytime I sort the values within sortable 2 for example I want the item to go up one position the counter still goes + 1. I would like the counter to only go + 1 or -1 when you move items from sortable 1 to sortable 2 and visa versa.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();

  });
   $(function() {
    $( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
      placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    });
    $( "#sortable2" ).disableSelection();

  });
  </script>
```

HTML

```
<span id="counter_text">0</span>
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
<li class="ui-state-default">Cat</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">Dog</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">Mouse</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
$( "#sortable2" ).droppable({
drop: function(event, ui) 
{
    $('#column_results').empty();
    $(this).append(ui.draggable);
    if($('#sortable2').hasClass("connectedSortable") === true)
    {
    if (counter <= 3) {
      counter++;
      $('#counter_text').text(counter);
      $("#counter_text_container").css("display","inline");
      $("#counter_text_container_1").css("display","none");
      $("#sortable2").css("border-color","grey");
      $('#btn_display_col').prop('disabled', false);    
    }
    if(counter > 3)
    {
     $("#sortable2").css("border-color","red"); 
     $("#counter_text_container").css("display","none");
     remainiing_counter = counter - 3;
     $("#counter_text_container_1").css("display","inline");
     $("#counter_text_remove").text(remainiing_counter);
     $('#btn_display_col').prop('disabled', true);
     $("#dialog-small-warning-cols").dialog({
                            autoOpen: false,
                            closeOnEscape: false,
                            width:250,
                            modal: true
                        });
                         $("#dialog-small-warning-cols").dialog({
                            dialogClass: "no-close",
                            buttons : {
                            "Ok" : function() {
                            //$('#country_id').load(document.URL +  ' #country_id');    
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
      }
    });
                        $("#dialog-small-warning-cols").dialog("open");
    }
        if(counter === 3)
    {
     $("#counter_text_container").css("display","inline");
       $("#counter_text_container_1").css("display","none");
       $("#sortable2").css("border-color","grey");
       $('#btn_display_col').prop('disabled', false);
     $('#btn_display_col').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    }
}

})

$( "#sortable1" ).droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $('#column_results').empty();
    counter--;
    if (counter <= 3) {
      $('#counter_text').text(counter);
      $("#counter_text_container").css("display","inline");
      $("#counter_text_container_1").css("display","none");
      $("#sortable2").css("border-color","grey");
      $('#btn_display_col').prop('disabled', false);    
    }
if(counter > 3)
    {
     $("#sortable2").css("border-color","red"); 
     $("#counter_text_container").css("display","none");
     remaining_counter = counter - 3;
     $("#counter_text_container_1").css("display","inline");
     $("#counter_text_remove").text(remaining_counter);
     $('#btn_display_col').prop('disabled', true);
    }
        if(counter === 3)
    {
       $("#counter_text_container").css("display","inline");
       $("#counter_text_container_1").css("display","none");
       $("#sortable2").css("border-color","grey");
       $('#btn_display_col').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This is happening in your `drop` function. My test script: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/usbkqxqo/ when `drop` executes, it's increasing `counter`. I would add a class to dropped items. If that class appears, do not increase the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/usbkqxqo/1/

```
...
drop: function(event, ui) {
      $('#column_results').empty();
      if (!ui.draggable.hasClass("dropped")) {
        ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
        counter++;
      }
      $(this).append(ui.draggable);
...
```

So when the `drop`, do a quick check to see if it's not `dropped` as a class. We add the class and increase `counter`. Now when you sort or move an object withing the 2nd sort, it will not increase `counter`.